# How do I inherit information from an instance of a class into another instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a basic banking program that has a class with customer profile information that will be inherited by several other classes for types of account that the customer will be able to access (e.g. checking account, savings account). I want the product class to inherit all information from the customer profile class and then add a balance for that particular service.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, name, cust_id, pin):
        self.name = name 
        self.cust_id = cust_id
        self.pin = pin

aidan_profile = Account('Aidan', 123456, 1234)

class CheckingAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, cust_id, pin, balance):
        Account.__init__(self, cust_id, pin)
        self.balance = balance

aidan_checking_account = CheckingAccount(aidan_profile, balance = 1000)
```

How do I pass through the profile information to an instance of the checking account class?

Thanks!

Comment: Fundamentally you don’t. You pass them one by one again, same as for `Account(...)`. You can take the values from the existing `Account` instance if you wish…

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use inheritance which is a "is a" relationship in a situation that really calls for composition which is a "has a" relationship.  In other words, a checking account "has a" customer profile associated with it.

Example:

```
class CustomerProfile:
    def __init__(self, name, cust_id, pin):
        self.name = name 
        self.cust_id = cust_id
        self.pin = pin

aidan_profile = CustomerProfile('Aidan', 123456, 1234)

class CheckingAccount:
    def __init__(self, profile, balance):
        self.profile = profile
        self.balance = balance

aidan_checking = CheckingAccount(aidan_profile, balance = 1000)

print(f"Customer {aidan_checking.profile.name} has a balance of {aidan_checking.balance} in checking.")
```

Output:

```
Customer Aidan has a balance of 1000 in checking.
```